# Dropdownlist in viewModel create view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, drop-down-menu

I have a "Leads" table which has a one to many relationship to "Employees" table. I also have created a leadViewModel class because I need some additional info for the Lead (Like addresses and phones etc.)

Here is the Lead class:

```
public partial class Leads
{
    [Key]
    public int LeadID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    public virtual Employees Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Employee Class:

```
public partial class Employees
{
    public Employees()
    {
        this.Leads = new HashSet<Leads>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }

    public virtual ICollection<Leads> Leads { get; set; }
}
```

leadViewModel:

```
public class LeadViewModel
{
    public Leads _leads { get; set; }
    public Addresses _addresses { get; set; }
    public Phones _phones { get; set; }
    public Emails _emails { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmployeesSelectListItem { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to have a dropdown list in the "Create" view. I am not sure what to do. Here is what I did and got errors.

LeadsController Create Get:

```
    // GET: Leads/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "FirstName");

        return View();
    }
```

LeadsController Create Post:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]        
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "_leads,_addresses,_phones,_emails,EmployeesSelectListItem")] LeadViewModel leadVM)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (TransactionScope leadScope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                db.Leads.Add(leadVM._leads);
                db.SaveChanges();

                leadScope.Complete();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "FirstName", leadVM._leads.EmployeeID);

        return View(leadVM);
    }
```

and finally the create view:

```
@model CL_AHR_CRM.ViewModels.LeadViewModel

...

   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model._leads.EmployeeID, "EmployeeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x._leads.EmployeeID, new SelectList(Model.EmployeesSelectListItem, "EmployeeID", "FirstName"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model._leads.EmployeeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I repeat my question: How can I use dropdownliast in a view when using a viewModel like this because obviously what I have done is not the way and is not working. I get the error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the Html.DropdownlistFor(...) in create view.

Comment: Remove `ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "FirstName");` and replace it with `leadVM.EmployeesSelectListItem` (in both the GET and POST) , but in the GET you need `LeadViewModel leadVM = new leadVM()` and then `return View(leadVM);

Comment: Would you please write the complete line of code? Sorry I'm a rookie!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view is based on typeof `LeadViewModel` but in the GET method you do not pass and instance of the model to the view, let alone populate the `EmployeesSelectListItem` property so in your `DropDownListFor()` method, `new SelectList(Model.EmployeesSelectListItem, ...` will throw and exception (the value of `Model` is `null`

Change the view model property to

```
public SelectList EmployeesSelectListItem { get; set; } // perhaps rename to EmployeeList?
```

Then change you GET method to

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  LeadViewModel model = new LeadViewModel();
  model.EmployeesSelectListItem = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "FirstName");
  return View(model);
}
```

Similarly in the POST method you need to use

```
leadVM.EmployeesSelectListItem = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "FirstName");
```

when you return the view (i.e when `ModelState` is invalid)

Then in the view use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x._leads.EmployeeID, Model.EmployeesSelectListItem, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thank you but now I get this error:
{"DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'EmployeeID'."}
Isn't there anything wrong with my Html.DropdownListFor(...)?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the include the change you need in the view - see update

Comment: I do not know how to thank you. You are a savior! Perfect I mean perfect answer. I will be thanking you all along my project. <3